# Testcontainers get image form private registry, docker login, credentials

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I have 2 Spring micro services (A and B) and I need to test micro service A against B. In micro service A I want to use test containers to start an image of micro service B and do my tests.

The micro service B image is in a private registry, if I wan to get the image in terminal I would do something like:

```
docker login --username USER --password PASS something.amazonaws.com
```

and then I can pull the image. I cannot find any clear documentation on how to configure this in the tests, using test containers. I saw that I can setup some properties in test containers, but not sure what to use.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. In `~/.testcontainers.properties` add `hub.image.name.prefix=custom.dockerhub.repository/`
2. Use `new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("<account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<imageName>:<version>").asCompatibleSubstituteFor("mongo")` for an existing container class. In your case, should use `GenericContainer`

You can find the documentation [here](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/image_name_substitution/#automatically%20-modifying-docker-hub-image-names)

Comment: In addition, Testcontainers will pick up the authentication credentials automagically, assuming you have an authorized Docker environment on your machine (which is the case after performing a `docker login`).

Comment: Yes, I was looking at it the wrong way, I wanted to have testcontainers do the docker login to not have every developer do a docker login to run the tests locally which doesn't make much sense, the rest is easy. Thanks!